# twitter api - nodejs problems

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

i am fairly new to NodeJS and the twitter api and I encountered some problems. Disclaimer: Because the terms of usage for the twitter api are strict i want to make clear that i am not going to profit anything off this project and i am not going to harm anyone's privacy using it.

So i have this html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bot.css" type="text/css">
    <title>document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <h1></h1>
    </div>
    <script src="bot.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

config.js :

```
module.exports = {
    consumer_key:         '',
    consumer_secret:      '',
    access_token:         '',
    access_token_secret:  '',
    timeout_ms:           60*1000,  // optional HTTP request timeout to apply to all requests.
    strictSSL:            true,     // optional - requires SSL certificates to be valid.
}
```

and the bot.js :

```
var Twit=require('twit');

var config=require('./config');

var T = new Twit(config);

let params = {
    q: 'polar-bear since:2011-07-11', 
    count: 2
}


function getData(err, data, response){
    for(let i=0;i<data.statuses.length;i++){
        console.log(`Tweet number ${i+1} : ${data.statuses[i].text}`);
    }
}


T.get('search/tweets', params, getData)



let page=document.querySelector('h1');
```

when i run only the bot.js file in terminal it works fine however 
 when i run the code on the web console i get 2 Reference 
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require ... 
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: module

Comment: You can't use `require` and `module` outside of the nodejs environment; these are baked into nodejs. You would need to use a transpiler, like babel/webpack, if you wish to use them outside of node.js such as your web console.

Comment: Agreed with @marshy101. However, I also suggest you try out https://parceljs.org/

This is a really simple 0 configuration bundler tool that can help you up and running. Though, what you also might wanna consider is making an node-js API + front end, and you're actual backend would proxy to the twitter API.